# Problems when build Skia for Android

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, skia

I try to build Skia for Android, there is my configuration:

```sh
ndk = "/root/workspace/ndk/android-ndk-r22/"
ndk_api=22
target_os="android"
target_cpu="arm"

is_official_build=false
is_component_build=false
```

After building skia successfully, I get `libskia.a` file, But cant work on my computer, its say:

```
error: undefined symbol atof
referenced by pngget.c
```

[error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrXol.png)

Android `gradle` configuration is:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.impactjs.ejecta"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        ndk {
            abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a'
        }
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                arguments '-DGCANVAS_WEEX=0', '-DGSTANDALONE=1'
            }
        }

    }

    ndkVersion '22.0.7026061'
}
```

My Cmake configuration is：

```
target_link_libraries(
  iwanmg

  z
  log
  jnigraphics
  gcanvas

  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/v8/libs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libwee8.a
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/skia/libs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libskia.a
)
```

please help~

Comment: It's very strange, can you test ```atof``` usage in your project without thirdparty stuff? Because it should work from the box.